# No GRUB boot menu after installing Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, uefi, bios

So I had Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my PC. Then I installed Kubuntu 20.04 alongside my Ubuntu. But after reboot the GRUB menu was not updated at all. It's like Kubuntu installation did not update my GRUB menu. I am using UEFI so maybe that is the problem? How do I add Kubuntu menu option to my GRUB now?

P.S. I tried Grub Customizer, but that did nothing.

Comment: Grub customizer replaces grub scripts with its own proxy versions. Do not know Grub customizer. May be better to just totally reinstall grub-efi-amd64. But if you have made changes to /etc/default/grub, you may want to back that file up. If you only have one system (or only one seen), you do not get a grub menu. Also they are turning off os-prober, you may need to manually turn it on, update grub & then turn it off for security reasons. Os-prober now turned off by default Dec 2021
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2469993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it, so I will share this with anyone else who might run into the same problem.

*Unfortunately, GRUB Customizer was no help to me. Even after I installed it to MBR and updated grub - it had no effect and my GRUB menu did not change at all.*

Then I noticed that there was a partition mounted on `/boot/efi` like this

```
$ df -h

Filesystem    Mounted on
/dev/sda1    /boot/efi
```

Then I created a new directory and mounted the `/dev/sda1` partition there

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/bootefi
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/bootefi
```

And then installed GRUB on this new partition like this

```
$ sudo apt install grub-efi -y
$ sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt/bootefi
```

After rebooting, finally my GRUB was updated and I saw my new Kubuntu entry!