# Grub menu boot up after reboot | Upgraded from Kubuntu 21.10 to Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kubuntu

I have upgraded my system from Kubuntu 21.10 to Kubuntu 22.04.
It's not Dual boot.
Every time I reboot my system, it boots to Grub Menu.

I have to type `GRUB > exit` in order to move forward to Kubuntu 22.04 Desktop login screen.
I found this article:

1. ([No GRUB boot menu after installing Kubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384133/no-grub-boot-menu-after-installing-kubuntu-20-04))

I am not sure if its legit. I ran this command below:

`krillavilla@Omega:~$ df -h`

This is output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G   10M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  938G   79G  812G   9% /
tmpfs           7.8G   84M  7.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /run/qemu
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M   74M  438M  15% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   88K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1       932G  353G  580G  38% /media/krillavilla/1TB
```

I have open Grub file `/etc/default/grub` but i am not sure if it's setup properly:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

***Update***

I ran `sudo update-grub` and this what it boots up:

[image: grub]
[image]

***Update***

Here is boot options:

[image]

***Update***

Using `efibootmgr` will solve my problem. This is why i Love Linux and despise Windows.

Here are my outputs for both `sudo efibootmgr` and `sudo efibootmgr -v`

```
krillavilla@Omega:~$ sudo efibootmgr
[sudo] password for krillavilla: 
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0001,0002,0000,0006,0007,9999
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* debian
Boot0003* debian
Boot0006* parrot
Boot0007* Solid State Disk
Boot9999* USB Drive (UEFI)

krillavilla@Omega:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0001,0002,0000,0006,0007,9999
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,2b21d0c8-a674-4a8a-8b0f-813451cbd918,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...e................
Boot0001* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,5b2c61f3-b112-46c1-ae79-59d90832672f,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0002* debian        HD(1,GPT,90c5cb5d-9548-4025-8025-27b247d4c58b,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003* debian        HD(1,GPT,5b2c61f3-b112-46c1-ae79-59d90832672f,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot0006* parrot        HD(1,GPT,8907e197-bdea-4f2d-88c4-20b901fbf855,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\parrot\grubx64.efi)
Boot0007* Solid State Disk      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-25-38-55-91-B1-4E-47)/HD(1,GPT,5b2c61f3-b112-46c1-ae79-59d90832672f,0x800,0x100000)..BO
Boot9999* USB Drive (UEFI)      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(16,0)..BO
```

I want to either get rid of `Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager` entry point or rearrange it. I am assuming Windows Boot Manager is causing grub menu boot up.

So this is syntax google shown me: `efibootmgr -b # -B`

In my case, I want to run command: `efibootmgr -b 0 -B`

I want to verify this before i destroy my SSD and i have to start from scratch.

***Update***

I meant the command that will fix my problem:

`sudo efibootmgr -o 2,1,3` and `sudo efibootmgr -b 3 -B`

Comment: Please run `sudo update-grub`and reboot. Report back.

Comment: @ChanganAuto it updated but it boot to grub menu

Comment: Open UEFI settings > Boot menu and check the boot order. You may find more than one "Ubuntu" entries. Try the other one.

Comment: @ChanganAuto check out post. If I select 'debian' it will go to grub. If I select 'ubuntu'  it will ask what Linux generic do I want to choose

Comment: So... You may not have a dual/multi-boot now but you had at same point Windows and Debian and those bootloaders are still in the ESP (EFI System Partition). Obviously the Grub menu is shown in this situation. You can use `efibootmgr` to clean-up. The update Grub again and the menu shouldn't be visible at boot.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Is there link or article i can use to follow along to clean up using this tool? `efibootmgr`

Comment: I googled it. i will post output of commands `sudo efibootmgr` and `sudo efibootmgr -v` to see if i get my understanding